# I cant simply await GetStringAsync?

Tags: c#, async-await, portable-class-library

I thought I could do i straight forward, but maybe there is something wrong with my setup? I'm trying to download a string in my app for logging in:

```
        private async void DoLogin()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string response = await client.GetStringAsync(Config.SERVER_URL + "/Login/");
```

All logic is removed, im going to add headers and so on, but VS2012 will no allow me to await that response.

I tried to follow the code [from here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx), but in my case I only get `Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string'`.

Why is that? Should'nt `GetStringAsync` simply return me a string? It returns a `Task<string>`, but do I have to wrap it in a method?

Comment: what do you mean "will no allow me to await that response"?

Comment: What is the error message that you are getting?  Also, `async void` methods are a very bad idea unless you're forced to use them because the method is an event handler.  The method should almost certainly return at least `Task`.

Comment: My DoLogin functions intent is to check user credentials agains /Login/ that returns a JSON string that indicates if the credentials are valid. I need to parse the response and see what it contains... for instance, if its ok then ill navigate the user to main menu. This is a Windows Phone project btw

Comment: @Jason94 You still didn't answer the question.  What is the error that you are getting when you try to do this?

Comment: Updated with code ive tried to follow

Comment: You haven't updated the question and you still haven't answered my question about what error it is that you're getting.

Comment: @Servy I did, i get the Cannot await 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string' error on the await client...

Answer (score 4):

Your code is perfectly fine. However: In order to use `async / await` in `portable class libaries` you need to add the NuGet package `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` to your project.

Also please note the comment of Servy to use the return type `Task` instead of `void`.